# How to make a container visible to the outside network, and handle I.P addresses in production

Tags: docker

I have:

- a Windows server on bare metal with Hyper-V
- Ubuntu server running in Hyper-V
- a Docker container with an NGINX web application running in Ubuntu server

Every time I run a Docker image it gets a new I.P. address on the Docker0 network interface. For production, I don't know how to make the Docker container visible to the external network. I also don't know how to handle the fact that the I.P address changes every time the image is run.

What's the correct way to:

- make a Docker container visible to the external network?
- handle Docker container I.P. addresses in a repeatable way in production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run your Docker container with `docker run`, you should use the `-p` switch to forward ports, for example:

```
docker run -p 80:80 nginx
```

This would route port 80 from the Ubuntu server to port 80 within the Nginx container.

You should check the Docker documentation on this at https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports.

When you have multiple containers and links, you should use `EXPOSE` in the Dockerfile as documented here: https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#expose.